# how to refund an order for an IOS App as a Developer?

Tags: ios, app-store, billing

How can I as a developer refund an order from one customer ?
When I get an email asking for a refund, how can I do that ?

Comment: Only Apple can do a refund, that should contact Apple iTunes support. This is because they are the seller, not you.

Comment: your consumer should contact to Apple (via iTunes) and clams the refund.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. It shows me again that Google/Android concepts are much better/cleverer then Apple/Itunes.

Comment: Since Apple is the seller and they charge the users account (credit card or whatever) they are the once who should do the refund.

Comment: @mcflysoft I'd draw just the opposite conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest that your user [contact iTunes support](http://www.imore.com/how-to-get-refund-itunes-app-store). At the moment, developers cannot personally issue refunds.

The good news? Apple covers the 30% - in other words, [you do not loose money on a refund.](http://www.imore.com/apple-charging-developers-100-app-refunds)